# I can't pip install Pandas on a Windows 10 by weels

Tags: python, pandas, windows, installation

I get an error when trying to install the Pandas package on a computer running Windows 10 with an Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8600K CPU @ 3.60GHz
pip install D:\ISZF\Weels\pandas-2.2.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: pandas-2.2.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

With respect,
Pavel  Stepanov

I try to install pandas by pip. But i have error during installation proucess!
Then i try to install pandas by weels and get error too!

Comment: way too little info - are you running it on powershell, or cmd, or any specific IDE (vscode, pycharm etc. What's your python version, what's pip error (pip should be the way to install new packages), did you try install any other package, is it only pandas that's failing (maybe your whole python installation is faulty)...

Comment: My crystal ball says you have a 32-bit Python and you're trying to install that amd64 (64-bit) wheel on it. Alternatively, you're trying to install that Python 3.12 (cp312) wheel on an older Python.